# Why req.getSession(false) returns null on disabling cookies in browser?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am learning Servlets and JSP. I have written an index.jsp page and a login servlet which are as follows -

index.jsp - (the welcome page)

```
<body>
<form action="login" method="post">
UserName:<input type="text" id="username" name="username">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
```

LoginServlet -

```
@WebServlet("/login")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
@Override   
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username=req.getParameter("username");
        HttpSession session=req.getSession(false);
        session.setAttribute("username",username);
        RequestDispatcher rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp");
        rd.forward(req,res);


}
```

It works if I keep cookies enabled in Edge browser. But when I disable cookies in Edge browser it shows error that - session is null. But when I set req.getSession(true), then on disabling cookies it works.

(I know that req.getSession(true) makes a new session if there is no existing session but req.getSession(false) returns null if there is no existing session. )

Can anyone please explain why this is happening? Also, when exactly does the new session object get created?